# Need advice for what to do with my first game idea

Tags: education

My friends and I have this idea to make a game. None of us have much experience with programming. We think our idea is to big too accomplish. Should we present our idea to an indie company that can make it, or scrap the idea and start with something smaller? If we start with something smaller, what can you recommend us to use since we have little experience with programming?

Comment: Ideas are a dime a dozen

Comment: It is very unlikely that somebody else will implement your idea - [Why Your Brilliant Game Idea Is Absolutely Worthless](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-your-brilliant-game-idea-absolutely-worthless-daniel-doan) ...and there is a really long path to learn how to implement it (several years) without any prior experience. But that does not mean impossible, if motivation persist!

Comment: As expressed above, nobody buys game ideas. Any team capable of making the game you have in mind will also have their own ideas for games they're passionate about making, so unless you're offering to fund development they're unlikely to be interested. As for whether to start small, YES. Make the tiniest game you can think of (Philipp's link has several good starting points), and even then, be prepared to cut it down smaller. The amount of work that goes into even the simplest game catches every new game developer by surprise.